# SpringBoot with RequestMapping on Application and another RequestMapping in controller classes, is that possible?

Tags: java, uri

I am learing SpringBoot and Rest api just now and in all examples I have seen, in every controller classes they have a @RequestMapping("/api/v1") and then some @GetMapping or simular.
But it feels like why am I writing a RequestMapping for every controller if the first URI mapping is the same for all controllers.

Is it possible to have a @RequestMapping in the SpringBootApplication that maps "/api/v1" and then in the controller classes then have another ®RequestMapping for subfolders like "/products" and simular.

I have tried to solve this, but I cant make it function.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class CommonApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(CommonApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping()
public class ProductController {

    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public String getProducts()
    {
        return "Hello from getProducts 12";
    }
}
```

I want this full URI "/api/v1/products" to function and return the String text. But I only get 404.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have request mapping in both application and controller class. Go through the documentation which is attached below once for having better understanding.

- https://zetcode.com/spring/requestmapping/